# date in the log file name

Tags: log4net, config, log4net-configuration, logfile

I want my logfile to end up like this :

2015-04-23.log (YYMMDD.log)

```
<root>
  <level value="DEBUG" />
  <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
</root>
<appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="logs\CTI\ServiceName" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Date" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
      <maximumFileSize value="20MB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="false" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline%exception" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
```

After running the code, the log file comes up as ServiceName_2015-04-23.log.2015-04-23.

What is the issue?

Answer (score 1):

The appender should look like this:

```
<appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="logs\CTI\ServiceName\" />
    <datePattern value="yyyy-MM-dd'.log'" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
    <maximumFileSize value="20MB" />
    <staticLogFileName value="false" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline%exception" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

The key is the datePattern where we add '.log' to the pattern.

Two years later...  Better late than never.

Answer (score 0):

You use rollingStyle=date, so log4net adds date in the end of file name.
You can find [useful config examples for RollingFileAppender class here](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html#rollingfileappender).

Comment: So I shouldn't use that parameter?

Comment: You should use this parameter. But it is implementation detail of RollingFileAppender class that it adds date as extension. You should consider to remove %utcdate from your file name and then log file will be ServiceName.log.2015-04-23.

Comment: You can't achieve this with log4net out of the box. You can try to create derived from RollingFileAppender class, but from my experience ServiceName.log.2015-04-23 is appropriate.

It's an implementation detail how RollingFileAppender threat rolling files: part of file name is fixed (ServiceName.log) and other part is for rolling and added automatically (2015-04-23 when you use date rolling, simple integers when you use rolling by file size).

Comment: @hal, that is not true.  You can do this out of the box, it is a standard use case for log4net.